# .click() function on element in array breaks my for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a problem with documents, i want to download for the user after he started a export in my client.

The generation of the documents works fine and so the first part of my code. so everything until the last for loop is just for context. the first document in the for loop is downloading but the `.click` function somehow breaks my for loop. So after this line of code nothing is happening. I also tried to click with jQuery using the id of the new element. I am a little bit lost on this.

`object.checked` is a Object which contains every entity and a boolean which says if a document should be created.

`object.usedFormats` is a Object which contains also every entity and a integer which says if it should be created as excel or pdf file.

```
var docs = []

for(var prop in object.checked) {
  if(object.checked[prop] == true) {
    var a = document.createElement('A')
    if(object.usedFormats[prop + 'Format'] == 0) {
      a.href = 'api/export?type=' + prop
      a.target = "_blank"
    } else if(object.usedFormats[prop + 'Format'] == 1) {
      //TODO pdf Aufruf sobald Feature verfügbar
      a.href = 'api/exportpdf?type=' + prop
      a.target = "_blank"
    } else {
      Toastr.error('Falsches Format für Export gewählt!')
    }
    docs.push(a)
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
  docs[i].id = 'dllink' + i
  document.body.appendChild(docs[i])
  docs[i].click()
  document.body.removeChild(docs[i])
}
```

Comment: It will help it you post a Jsfiddle for your issue. It will make it easier to udnerstand and test, and you will probably get an answer faster.

Comment: It might be irrelevant, but why don't you put `;` after lines? JS does not always understand code without `;` correctly